# Can i copy data from other system partition?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, windows-backup

Since i have dual boot and i lost my access to windows, i need to make backup for some files i was working on. I remember on windows(to ubuntu) it didnt allow me to do it , only formatting partition.
Short story 
My windows system is dying, i lost my system key(its on disc but not on bios , and i cannot activate it). Ive tried to restore system , even deleting most of my data in process.But now all i see is purple screen when i try to choose windows.

Comment: Okay... looks like i can get to sys by bios,  but boot options doesnt work. I think disc might be dying (4-5yo laptop)

Answer (score 1):

Your Ubuntu operating system can read the Windows file system, assuming you didn't encrypt it with Bitlocker. You should open your file manager and see the Windows partition. When you double click the drive it will mount the partition is a drive and you can then copy the data.

Answer (score 0):

Stock Windows doesn't support the Unix file systems, but most Linux distros have the NTFS filesystem already installed.

Use:

```
fdisk -l
```

to identify the disk(s) with an NTFS partition. The disk name is in the form `/dev/sdXn`, where `X` is `a,b,c...` (`sda` is your first hard drive, `sdb` the second... and so on) and `n` is a partition number.

Then for each disk, create an empty directory in `/mnt`:

```
mkdir /mnt/windisk1
```

Attach that file system to your file hierarchy:

```
mount -t ntfs --read-only /dev/sda1 /mnt/windisk1
```

If everything went well, your Windows disk appears as /mnt/windisk1